# Background task form not working as expected and freezes GUI

Tags: vb.net

I have main window form of my program. There is a long task that i want to put into different thread. I have another small form (FrmCircularProgress) which is shown to the user on top when that task is running, this is normal simple form and nothing in it. Issue is when long task is running and my waiting form shows up (FrmCircularProgress) it seems to be not responding (freezed) because i cannot move it for instance during the process. I do not know why since task is running on different thread waiting form should be responsive. Please of your support.

Note that and what is funny i use exactly similar approach in many other places - with this _pic.Shown, AddressOf XXX where inside method for XXX i place code which i want to put on diffrent thread and all works means FrmCircularProgress is responsive. This is the first time it happens and i have no clue the cause of it.

On top of main form class:

```
Private WithEvents _pic As FrmCircularProgress
Private _tsk As Task(Of Boolean)
Button handler where long running task is raised:

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
      Try
         _pic = New FrmCircularProgress(eCircularProgressType.Donut)
         AddHandler _pic.Shown, AddressOf DoTheJob
         _pic.ShowDialog()
      Catch ex As Exception
      Finally
         RemoveHandler _pic.Shown, AddressOf DoTheJob
      End Try
End Sub
```

Task itself:

```
Public Sub DoTheJob(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        _tsk = Task.Run(Function()
        '--Run lenghty task
        Dim resu = False
        Try
           InitGrid()
           resu = True
        Catch ex As Exception
          _pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() MessageBoxEx.Show(_pic, ex.ToString())
        Finally
          '--Close form once done (on GUI thread)
          _pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() _pic.Close()))
        End Try
        Return resu
End Function)
End Sub
```

Since it's in diffrent thread not sure if you need them to see but i am showing them:

InitGrid:

```
Public Sub InitGrid() Handles _editDictionaryForm.Updated, _addDictionaryForm.Updated
      If InvokeRequired Then
           Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf InitGrid))
      Else
           Try
              BindArticlesData()
              InitializeGridBasiscSettings()
           Catch ex As Exception
           End Try
      End If
End Sub

Private Sub BindArticlesData()
       If InvokeRequired Then
              Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf BindArticlesData))
       Else
          Try
             RemoveHandler gridDic.DataBindingComplete, AddressOf SuperGridControl1DataBindingComplete
             AddHandler gridDic.DataBindingComplete, AddressOf SuperGridControl1DataBindingComplete
             gridDic.PrimaryGrid.DataSource = Nothing
             Dim dada = CInt(DirectCast(cbLang.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("Id"))
             gridDic.PrimaryGrid.DataSource = _dictionary.GetDataSet(dada, txtFilterDE.Text)
          Catch ex As Exception
          End Try
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeGridBasiscSettings()
       If InvokeRequired Then
                Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf InitializeGridBasiscSettings))
       Else
           //simple grid layout adjustments
       End If
End Sub
```

**What i did so far:**

Since so far i realized that it's right to use invoke() when dealing from different threads nevertheless it is still blocking the main thread therefore i thought maybe it's good to extend variable data, fill it in in Invoke, however set data to grid's datasource outside Invoke to not block GUI. Nevertheless for some reason the issue seems still the same.

```
Private Sub BindArticlesData()

    Dim data As DataSet  ' <=======put outside Invoke
    Invoke(Sub()
    RemoveHandler gridDic.DataBindingComplete, AddressOf SuperGridControl1DataBindingComplete
    AddHandler gridDic.DataBindingComplete, AddressOf SuperGridControl1DataBindingComplete
    gridDic.PrimaryGrid.DataSource = Nothing
    Dim dada = CInt(DirectCast(cbLang.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("Id"))
    data = _dictionary.GetDataSet(dada, txtFilterDE.Text)
    End Sub)

    gridDic.PrimaryGrid.DataSource = data   'fill outside Invoke the result

End Sub
```

**EDIT for further discussion:**

```
Private Sub BindArticlesData()
        Dim data As DataSet
        RemoveHandler gridDic.DataBindingComplete, AddressOf SuperGridControl1DataBindingComplete
        AddHandler gridDic.DataBindingComplete, AddressOf SuperGridControl1DataBindingComplete

        gridDic.PrimaryGrid.DataSource = Nothing

        Invoke(Sub()
              Dim dada = CInt(DirectCast(cbLang.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("Id"))

              data = _dictionary.GetDataSet(dada, txtFilterDE.Text)
         End Sub)

         gridDic.PrimaryGrid.DataSource = data

End Sub
```

Comment: If the slow part is updating the UI, then you start a thread and call Invoke to update the UI. I think the UI will still freeze. Invoke is used to [execute something inside the UI thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @the_lotus what exactly should i change within my code,can you post as an answer, i am confused

Comment: Why would you close out this exact question from yesterday and ask it again? There was a great discussion about this, evidently from all of the comments you still didn't make changes and are expecting us to do the work... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651952/background-task-form-not-working-as-expected, you removed it and now the discussion is gone as well.

Comment: You Invoke too much. Only invoke the bare minimum required by the UI. This means don't invoke inside of InitGrid as well as BindArticlesData and InitializeGridBasiscSettings; once invoked inside InitGrid any subsequent invocations will be unnecessary as the code is now running on the UI. In this case, you don't need to remove and add handlers on the UI thread, so you have shown evidence of at least one instance of over-invocation. I'm sure you have more - and if you do too much on the UI it will cause it to become unresponsive.

Comment: This being said, I recreated your situation in a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and **my form is responsive** so the offending code must be elsewhere.

Comment: @djv Finally i found what was the issue, it was with grid.ColumnAutoSizeMode = ColumnAutoSizeMode.AllCells which is placed in InitializeGridBasiscSettings() Is there any event to that property i could catch when ColumnAutoSizeMode is start/stop?

Comment: @Dino please clarify `Is there any event to that property i could catch when ColumnAutoSizeMode is start/stop?` which doesn't make sense